# ionic3 slides swipe sensitivity

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

In my Ionic3 app, I have a `slides` component with a bunch of slides, and I want to be able to `click` on each of them. So code would look like:

```
<ion-slides>
  <ion-slide *ngFor="let s of slides" (click)="onClick()">Slide</ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

The problem I have is that very often, when I try to click on the slide, it actually does a `swipe` of the current slide and shows the next one, therefore the click never happens. This happens mostly using a tablet, as I guess my finger is less stable and if the click is not perfect then it will slide.

Is there any way to make the click less sensitive (so that even a small variation of distance between down and up event is recognized as click not swipe)?

Comment: does `event.preventDefault()` work?

Comment: @suraj on which event? actually the question is not clear enough, let me change it, I want it to click but it keeps swiping no the other way around

Comment: I meant `(click)="onClick($event)` and in `onClick(){event.preventDefault()}`. As I understand you _dont want it to slide on click but rather call the function_

Comment: @suraj the click is not called

Comment: try `(tap)` instead of click...

Comment: actually the question is more generic that slides, it kind of applies to every component but in the slides it is a lot more annoying

Comment: @suraj `tap` does not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of options available that ionic don't list but you can see them here in the library that ionic slides uses:

http://idangero.us/swiper/api/

Setting the Touches **threshold** to a reasonable value should help.

If you have a reference to your slider, you can simply say `this.slider.threshold = 100;`

Answer (score 2):

You can just first get your swiper using querySelector:

```
let mySwiper = document.querySelector('yourSwiperSelector');
```

Then just change the treshold:

```
mySwiper.threshold = 100;
```

It worked for me. In my case it was ionic2-calendar and my selector looked like this:

```
let mySwiper = document.querySelector('.swiper-container')['swiper'];
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<ion-slides pager>
  <ion-slide *ngFor="let s of slides" (click)="onClick()">Slide</ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Comment: To improve your answer maybe you can add some description text

Comment: or just not copy-paste the bit of code I put in my question and pretend it is an answer of some kind